# Unable to access controls using VisualTreeHelper

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

So, in my page I have added a Pivot. I name the Pivot `MainPivot`. Inside the `MainPivot` I've edited the `Title Template`. Inside the TitleTemplate, I've added 2 TextBlocks. One is called `AppTitle` and the other is called `UserText`

What I want to do is set the text of both `AppTitle` and `UserText` using `C#`. To do that, I managed to get the `VisualTreeHelper` from [this link](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7). Although its "How to access inside ListBox" I added a few changes to see if it worked.

So My code.
XAML for the edited `MainPivot`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MainPivotEditedTemplate">
 <StackPanel x:Name="Stak" Orientation="Vertical" Width="0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="AppTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="443" Margin="0,0,-443,0" FontSize="22"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="UserText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="443" Margin="0,0,-443,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="23"/>
 </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here's the code for the `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
{
  var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);      

  if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;     
}
```

Here's the code that's meant to change the TextBlock's Texts:

```
public MainMenu()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  Pivot apptitle = this.MainPivot.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as Pivot;
  Pivot usertext = this.MainPivot.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) as Pivot;

  TextBlock _apptitle = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<TextBlock>(apptitle);
  TextBlock _usertext = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<TextBlock>(usertext);     

  _apptitle.Text = "APPLICATION TITLE";
  _usertext.Text = "USER TEXT";      
}
```

Now my problem is that when I debug the app, it gives me an error saying:
`Reference is not a valid visual DependencyObject.`

and shows this line in the VisualTreeHelper method:
`var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);`

Can anyone please help me? All I want to do is access those 2 textblock's and change the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do it as a template really?

Why not just set the Title

```
<phone:Pivot.Title>
    <StackPanel Name="Stak" Orientation="Vertical" Width="0">
        <TextBlock Name="AppTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="443" Margin="0,0,-443,0" FontSize="22"/>
        <TextBlock Name="UserText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="443" Margin="0,0,-443,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="23"/>
    </StackPanel>
</phone:Pivot.Title>
```

and access TextBlocks directly in code behind

```
AppTitle.Text = "APPLICATION TITLE";
UserText.Text = "USER TEXT";
```

Comment: This is helpful and I thank you for that :). The reason being is that I've always wanted to know how to access controls e.g. textblocks etc which are inside templates i.e. The pivot Template. Do you know how I can access controls from inside data templates?

Comment: @Ahmed.C Well, if you must do that, it might be better to search for item by name. Searching for just a TextBlock is risky. Your code is wrong because you use ContainerFromIndex and at one point send null to FindFirstElementInVisualTree. Why not search inside the MainPivot.Title by name, and find those too and then edit them? There are plenty of examples online how do search by name. Still, in this particular case, I don't see a reason to do it.